# Refresh doesn't update owner-draw ListBox item height

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, ownerdrawn

I have `ListBox` with `DrawMode = OwnerDrawVariable`. When I dynamically change height of one (or more) of item and do

```
listBox1.Refresh();
```

then the new item height is ignored, it will only repaint properly:

[image: lalala]

`Ok` - is initially *expanded* item, `Not ok`- is expanded by mouse.

The measure item code is not complicated and I have checked with breakpoint, `e.ItemHeight = 90` at the end, however, item is still having height of `20`.

```
    private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // ... get item
        e.ItemHeight = 20;
        if(!collapsed)
            e.ItemHeight = 20 + 10 * n; // n - number of child rows
    }
```

Question: is it ok to do (which works)

```
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = list; // list of my items
```

or do I miss some method (tried `Invalidate` and `Update`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-measuring existing items in ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571059/re-measuring-existing-items-in-listbox)

Comment: @LarsTech, where have you been month ago? =D Btw, that "solution" with reassigning `DataSource` works surprisingly well so far (it doesn't flickers much). For some reasons `ListBox` is able to maintain `SelectedIndex` (or `SelectedItem`), but **not** `SelectedItems` (with `SelectionMode=MiltiExtended`), so I may come back to your solution (with subclassing listbox to recreate handle) some day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, OnMeasureItem Event worked only if I deleted all items, and added them back again. I don't work in C# so code is in delphi, but it should work well enough.

```
var
  tmp: TStrings;
  I: Integer;
begin
  tmp := TStrings.Create();
  try
    for I := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
      tmp.Add(ListBox1.Items[I]);

    ListBox1.Items.Clear;


    for I := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
      ListBox1.Items.Add(tmp[I]);

  finally
    tmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It worked for me, since I used TListBox only as a control to DISPLAY information, not to STORE them so I just made loop without any additional variales.

Comment: Reassigning `DataSource` does the same thing (clearing `ListBox` items and assigning them back), but with less overhead (no need for `tmp`).